# How to call Math.round with string as parameter?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use this function to round to decimals

```
function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
  }
```

But I am getting error message

```
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert the string to a number first, for instance:

```
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(Number(value + 'e' + decimals)) + 'e-' + decimals);
  // ----------------------^^^^^^^----------------------^
}
```